# Фильтр и сортировка по вычисляемому полю

Tags: yii

Добрый день! Такая проблема.
Есть таблица со студентами: StudID, StudSurName,StudLastName, ...
Связанная с ней таблица с баллами: PointID, PointStudFK(внешний ключ), Points(баллы).
Связь Has_many.

```
'points' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Points', array('PointStudFK' => 'StudID'))
```

По каждому студенту сумму баллов я вывел в CGridView, а вот фильтр сделать не получается.
Фильтр работает, но сравнивает значение с суммой всех баллов студентов, а не по каждому.
Виртуальное поле

```
private $_point= null;
```

Сеттер и геттер
getSumPoints() - функция вычисления суммы баллов по отдельному студенту

```
public function getPoint()
{
    if ($this->_point === null && $this->points!== null)
    {
        $this->_point = $this->points->getSumPoints($this->StudID);
    }
    return $this->_point;
}
public function setPoint($value)
{
    $this->_point = $value;
}
```

search()

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->together = true;
$criteria->distinct = true;
$criteria->with = array('points'=>array(
'select' => array('SUM(Points) as total')));
if(!empty($this->pointExp1)) $criteria->having = "total = {$this->point}";
```

Надо сгруппировать, но не знаю как.

Comment: а моно пример того что вы хотите в запросе получить?

Comment: SELECT StudID, SUM( Points ) AS sumP
FROM  `tbl_students` , `tbl_points` 
WHERE PointStudFK = StudID
GROUP BY PointStudFK

StudID|sumP: 1|24; 2|19; 3|20; ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

интуиция подсказывает, что вам нужно добавить

```
$criteria->group='PointStudFK'
```

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделал.